# Test against multiple conditions on a filter in ramda

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I am currently doing the following:

```
(projects, query, domain) => compose(
  filter<Project>(propEq('domain', domain)),
  filter<Project>(propSatisfies(test(new RegExp(query)), 'name')),
)(projects)
```

However, I was wondering if there was a way to avoid the extra iteration by combining the tests. I looked into `and` and `allPass`, but neither really meet my parameters. Ideally, I would have something like this:

```
filter<Project>(
  all([
    propEq('domain', domain),
    propSatisfies(test(new RegExp(query)), 'name'),
  ]),
);
```

Is this possible in ramda?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess this should do what you need

```
filter<Project>(allPass([
  propEq('domain', domain),
  propSatisfies(test(new RegExp(query)), 'name')
]))
```

Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`and`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#and), though it's only for two arguments.

I also wonder what's wrong with joining the predicates with plain `&&`s, starting from the least probable.